# cryptography install with pip3

Tags: python, ubuntu

I've been trying to install cryptography python-3.4.3 on ubuntu 14.04 LTS. After downloading the libbfi and libssl, when I'm using pip3 to install cryptography. This is what I'm getting:-

```
Command /usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools,
tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_gogol/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__,
'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-s1t_s_oy-record/install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_gogol/cryptography Storing debug log for failure in
/home/gogol/.pip/pip.log
```

If I run pip3 install again, this is what I'm getting.

```
gogol@gogol-Vostro-3558tio:~$ pip3 install cryptography 

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>

    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 70, in <module>

    import packaging.version
ImportError: No module named 'packaging'

gogol@gogol-Vostro-3558tio:~$
```

please, can anyone help me? I have looked up extensively all answers here regarding cryptography, but still can't make anything out of this. A detailed answer would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All credits go to this blog: https://odedrabhavesh.blogspot.ca/2017/02/importerror-no-module-named.html

Since you are using python3, try the following with root permission:

```
apt-get purge -y python3-pip
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python3 ./get-pip.py
```

Then try `pip install` again.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing the packaging module, which is needed as a dependency.  Try:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip

pip3 install packaging
```

then retry installing cryptography.